# Problems in quantum computing that tolerate high error rate

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction

It is proven that quantum computers outperform classical computers in several algorithms. Meaning with enough qubits quantum computer will find answer to large enough search faster than classical computer.

That assumes, that error rates for quantum computer are low. What are algorithms where quantum computer is assymptotically faster AND tolerate high error rates? Are error rates of today quantum computers already low  enough for those algorithms even if high number of qubits could be used in calculations?

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question.  Do any of these sound like the questions you are trying to ask... Are quantum computers destined to outperform classical? What algorithms allow a quantum computer to outperform classical computers?  How does quantum computation deal with error mitigation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.